# How can I monitor a log file and insert timestamps, using Perl?

Tags: perl, tail, gnuwin32

I have an application which generates logs in append mode, but the logs are not timestamped.

Is it possible to use `tail -f` with some option, or a `perl` script to monitor writes to this file and prefix them with a timestamp?

Given that I am running Windows without Cygwin, could I avoid using bash or any other Unix shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using GNU tail, then you should be able to use GNU [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).

```
C:\test>tail -F file  | gawk.exe "{s=systime(); print strftime(\"%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S\",s),$0}"
```

Comment: That's great! I already have all binaries from UnxUtils and had not thought of gawk… thank you!

Comment: download GNU tool from `gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html`. the ones from `UnxUtils`  are outdated

Comment: I used it to update the telnet logs with time-stamp, but the gawk is not appending the timestamp. C:\tail.exe -F "C:\Test.txt"  | C:\gawk.exe "{s=systime(); print strftime(\"%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S\",s),$0}"

Answer (score 2):

You could use a while loop:

```
tail -f logfile | while read line;
do
    echo $(date) $line;
done
```

Implies running date for each line though.  You could use the format output options of the date command to get the timestamp format you want.

I very basic Perl equivalent would be (script.pl):

```
while (<>) {
    my $date = scalar localtime;
    print $date . " " . $_;
}

tail -f logfile | perl script.pl
```

Comment: hah. I forgot to tell that I am using Windows, and that I would like to avoid a Cygwin installation :) Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @Benoit - No worries - maybe retag?  Someone will be along any minute with the Perl version.

Comment: the perl script is very good too… I wish I could accept more than one answer.

Comment: To avoid the `echo` with backticks, you can pass the `$line` as an argument to `date`: `date +"%c $line"` (provided your `$line` doesn't contain percent codes which `date` would interpret as formatting instructions).

Answer (score 1):

May be could you use a perl script with File::Tail and DateTime ?

```
use File::Tail;
use DateTime;
my $ref=tie *FH,"File::Tail",(name=>$ARGV[0]);
while (<FH>) {
    my $dt = DateTime->now();
    print "[", $dt->dmy(), " ",$dt->hms(),"] $_";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [`File::Tail`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTail) module was designed specifically for reading in appended log files.

It may be worth a look.